# Remove extra query string parameters from ItemNotFoundUrl

Tags: sitecore

I'm using sitecore 5.3 and need to be able to remove the extra query string parameters that sitecore inserts *(item=%2faeuaoeu&user=extranet\Anonymous&site=thl)* when redirecting to the 404 page specified in ItemNotFoundUrl.

In Sitecore 6 I can set

```xml
<setting name="RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect" value="true"/>
```

and it works but that setting doesn't exist in sitecore 5.3

I need it so I can fix [this asp.net vulnerability](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx)

**Edit: Sitecore's official response has been described in this [article](http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2010/09/24/asp-net-vulnerability-2416728-and-sitecore/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides item not found, there is also layout not found page with the same behavior.

You will need to create a custom version of Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest processor where you will be able to call custom version of the following methods:

```cs
private void HandleItemNotFound(HttpRequestArgs args)
private void HandleLayoutNotFound(HttpRequestArgs args)
```

Within these methods, you won't be attaching any query strings:

```cs
// old code:
WebUtil.Redirect(WebUtil.AddQueryString(itemNotFoundUrl, new string[] { "item", localPath, "user", userName, "site", str4 }), false);
}

//new code:
WebUtil.Redirect(itemNotFoundUrl, false);
```

I would recommend contacting official Sitecore tech support for a solution though.

Comment: Please check the official solution from Sitecore here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Security/ASP,-d-,NET%20Vulnerability%202416728.aspx

Comment: Alex, can you comment as to why the 'user' query appears in the first place? Is it a Sitecore client function? OMS related? Thanks!